# Where can i found the Windows Desktop C# API?

Tags: c#, windows, api, desktop

i want to develop an app for manage the desktop in windows using C# (similar to spaces on mac or multiple desktops on linux). I found some information about connecting the win32 api with c# but i don't want that, i want to manage the windows desktop directly with c#, do you know the way?

Comment: You failed to describe what sort of specific activity you want to perform with the desktop. The native win32 api contains functions for most tasks.

Comment: dude i say...manage desktops on windows (create 2 or more virtual desktops via c#) i describe in the post ok?

Comment: 1) Windows doesn't have "spaces" - there's one "desktop" for each logon.  If people get anal about organizing their "desktop", they usually just create a folder on "the desktop" and put a bunch of links in it.  2) Anything you can do from the Win32 API, you should be able to do from C#.

Comment: @paulsm4 - I'm glad someone was able to read between the lines on this one...

Comment: @M.Babcock what is the purpose of make a question if your answer is not constructive. You say me that native win32 api contains funcitons for most taks, but i dont want win32; i want c# ok?

Comment: @innuendoreplay - You realize that the answer you selected involves invoking the win32 API right?

Comment: @M.Babcock Exactly but its the point...i'm questioning if is any way to perform that without win32. Anyway thanks ;-)

Comment: @innuendoreplay - You **are** using the Win32 API by using the selected answer. You appear to be misinformed or misguided. Either way, the answer provided goes against what you said you wanted.

Comment: @M.Babcock I selected because it's useful for me, in that answer the author made clear the necessity of use the windows API (you can read) for my purpose, and share me a good resource.

Comment: This question is like saying I want to drive the car to the store but I don't want to use the gas pedal or steering wheel.  I would suggest you get a firm understanding of how the windows programming environment works along with the .Net Framework (C#) before you attempt to build a management application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I found some information about connecting the win32 api with c# but i
>   don't want that.

To interact with Windows in a standardized fashion you need to use its API; the same is true for any library, i.e. how else would you to "connect" to it? Using the Win32 API in c# is fairly similar to using it in any other language.

There are [hundreds of examples](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx) of how to do this in c#.

[Further reading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682127%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which suggests that you can create multiple desktop objects.